# Getting dictionary entries sorted by their keys

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have following dictionary:

```
map = {'`s_h_o_seq_id`': 'STRING', '`s_h_o_identifier`': 'STRING', '`c`': 'STRING', '`c_system`': 'STRING', '`c_system_name`': 'STRING', '`display_name`': 'STRING', '`original_text`': 'STRING', '`status_c`': 'STRING', '`efc_time_high`': 'STRING', '`efc_time_low`': 'STRING', '`efc_time_v`': 'STRING', '`v_type`': 'STRING', '`v_text`': 'STRING', '`v_unit`': 'STRING', '`v_c`': 'STRING', '`v_c_system`': 'STRING', '`v_c_system_name`': 'STRING', '`v_c_display_name`': 'STRING', '`ctd_by`': 'STRING', '`ctd_date`': 'STRING', '`updtd_by`': 'STRING', '`updtd_date`': 'STRING', '`is_deleted`': 'STRING', '`pat_practice_id`': 'STRING', '`release`': 'STRING', '`section_name`': 'STRING', '`parent_entity_name`': 'STRING', '`class_c`': 'STRING', '`com_mood_c`': 'STRING', '`t_id_root`': 'STRING', '`t_id_extn`': 'STRING'}
```

I tried to obtain its list of its entries sorted by keys as follows:

```
print(sorted(map.items(), key=lambda kv: (kv[0])))
```

This prints:

```
[('`c_system_name`', 'STRING'), ('`c_system`', 'STRING'), ('`c`', 'STRING'), ('`class_c`', 'STRING'), ('`com_mood_c`', 'STRING'), ('`ctd_by`', 'STRING'), ('`ctd_date`', 'STRING'), ('`display_name`', 'STRING'), ('`efc_time_high`', 'STRING'), ('`efc_time_low`', 'STRING'), ('`efc_time_v`', 'STRING'), ('`is_deleted`', 'STRING'), ('`original_text`', 'STRING'), ('`parent_entity_name`', 'STRING'), ('`pat_practice_id`', 'STRING'), ('`release`', 'STRING'), ('`s_h_o_identifier`', 'STRING'), ('`s_h_o_seq_id`', 'STRING'), ('`section_name`', 'STRING'), ('`status_c`', 'STRING'), ('`t_id_extn`', 'STRING'), ('`t_id_root`', 'STRING'), ('`updtd_by`', 'STRING'), ('`updtd_date`', 'STRING'), ('`v_c_display_name`', 'STRING'), ('`v_c_system_name`', 'STRING'), ('`v_c_system`', 'STRING'), ('`v_c`', 'STRING'), ('`v_text`', 'STRING'), ('`v_type`', 'STRING'), ('`v_unit`', 'STRING')]
```

Consider first three tuples in the above output list:

```
('`c_system_name`', 'STRING'), ('`c_system`', 'STRING'), ('`c`', 'STRING')
```

I wanted them in exactly reverse order, that is:

```
('`c`', 'STRING'), ('`c_system`', 'STRING'), ('`c_system_name`', 'STRING')
```

So I tried to get rid of those single quotes in keys, just in case they were causing trouble:

```
sorted_map = sorted(map.items(), key=lambda kv: (kv[0][1:len(kv)-1]))
```

The output was:

```
[('`s_h_o_seq_id`', 'STRING'), ('`s_h_o_identifier`', 'STRING'), ('`c`', 'STRING'), ('`c_system`', 'STRING'), ('`c_system_name`', 'STRING'), ('`display_name`', 'STRING'), ('`original_text`', 'STRING'), ('`status_c`', 'STRING'), ('`efc_time_high`', 'STRING'), ('`efc_time_low`', 'STRING'), ('`efc_time_v`', 'STRING'), ('`v_type`', 'STRING'), ('`v_text`', 'STRING'), ('`v_unit`', 'STRING'), ('`v_c`', 'STRING'), ('`v_c_system`', 'STRING'), ('`v_c_system_name`', 'STRING'), ('`v_c_display_name`', 'STRING'), ('`ctd_by`', 'STRING'), ('`ctd_date`', 'STRING'), ('`updtd_by`', 'STRING'), ('`updtd_date`', 'STRING'), ('`is_deleted`', 'STRING'), ('`pat_practice_id`', 'STRING'), ('`release`', 'STRING'), ('`section_name`', 'STRING'), ('`parent_entity_name`', 'STRING'), ('`class_c`', 'STRING'), ('`com_mood_c`', 'STRING'), ('`t_id_root`', 'STRING'), ('`t_id_extn`', 'STRING')]
```

But this seems to mess up everything (keys `'s...'` appear before `'c...'`):

```
('`s_h_o_seq_id`', 'STRING'), ('`s_h_o_identifier`', 'STRING'), ('`c`', 'STRING')
```

Why I am getting above output and how can I get what I desire?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I sort a dictionary by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key)

Comment: nope...I knew I can use `sorted()` which is what is answered in that question. My question is why its not working for me / for my set of keys, what mistake I am doing. And I was indeed doing silly mistake of having `len(kv)` instead of `len(kv[0])` as you can read in comments and answers below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is not the sorting, but the *contents of your keys*. Those backticks *also count when sorting*, and the backtick is sorted after underscores, but before lower-case letters:

```
>>> sorted(["`", "a", "_"])
['_', '`', 'a']
```

This is why `` "`c_system_name`" `` sorts before `` "`c_system`" ``, because the `` '`' `` backtick character at the end of `` "`c_system`" `` sorts after the underscore at the same position in `` "`c_system_...`" ``.

Sort without backticks:

```
sorted(map.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[0].strip("`"))
```

or don't create keys with backticks around their value.

Demo:

```
>>> print(sorted(map.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[0].strip("`")))
[('`c`', 'STRING'), ('`c_system`', 'STRING'), ('`c_system_name`', 'STRING'), ('`class_c`', 'STRING'), ('`com_mood_c`', 'STRING'), ('`ctd_by`', 'STRING'), ('`ctd_date`', 'STRING'), ('`display_name`', 'STRING'), ('`efc_time_high`', 'STRING'), ('`efc_time_low`', 'STRING'), ('`efc_time_v`', 'STRING'), ('`is_deleted`', 'STRING'), ('`original_text`', 'STRING'), ('`parent_entity_name`', 'STRING'), ('`pat_practice_id`', 'STRING'), ('`release`', 'STRING'), ('`s_h_o_identifier`', 'STRING'), ('`s_h_o_seq_id`', 'STRING'), ('`section_name`', 'STRING'), ('`status_c`', 'STRING'), ('`t_id_extn`', 'STRING'), ('`t_id_root`', 'STRING'), ('`updtd_by`', 'STRING'), ('`updtd_date`', 'STRING'), ('`v_c`', 'STRING'), ('`v_c_display_name`', 'STRING'), ('`v_c_system`', 'STRING'), ('`v_c_system_name`', 'STRING'), ('`v_text`', 'STRING'), ('`v_type`', 'STRING'), ('`v_unit`', 'STRING')]
```

The [`str.strip()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) is a much better way of removing the backticks than using slicing, because it'll remove zero or more backticks from start and end, and leave other characters alone.

Your own attempt with `kv[0][1:len(kv)-1]` was using the wrong `len()`; `len(kv)` is always `2`, you wanted `len(kv[0])`. Not that you ever need to calculate the length in slicing, as negative slices already count from the end: `kv[0][1:-1]` removes the first and last characters.

Comment: I'd add also that the second OP's version almost works, but it should be `key=kv[0][1:len(kv[0])-1]` or `key=kv[0][1:-1]`.

Comment: @bereal: yes, I was addressing that too.

Answer (score 1):

You should change `len(kv)` to `len(kv[0])`:

```
sorted_map = sorted(map.items(), key=lambda kv: (kv[0][1:len(kv[0])-1]))
```